# Creating a new transactional email

Tags: orders, transactional-mail

I would like to have the ability to send customers an email from my store asking about their experience.

Currently the only emails I have access to are on transaction, order cancellation drop down, shipping confirmation or order cancellation.

I would want to have a "customer followup" option that would send a new template.

What is the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is set-up a cron that runs every 15 mins or so. Here you can get a collection of all orders that have been processed since the last cron run. The you can build your own email template and send these emails that you need to.

To create a new transaction email template follow these steps shown in [Adding transactional email template to transaction email list by custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/3680/158)